# AS3 - mailto is opening a new browser window

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

Intro to the problem -
With AS3 I want that when people clicks an email address, it opens their email program. Therefore I do this:

```
mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sendEmail);

function sendEmail(e:MouseEvent):void{<br />
     navigateToURL(new URLRequest("mailto:name@domainname.com"));<br />
}
```

The problem: 
Every time a user clicks the movie clip, it opens their email program. However, the browser is opening a new window as well. How can I avoid the browser from opening the new window when clicking the movie clip that has the email address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a very easy answer to this.  Navigate to URL will open a new browser window or do it in itself depending on how specified, if no window is open it opens one regardless.  Use `sendToURL`instead of `navigateToURL`, I just tested and it works fine.

```
sendToURL(new URLRequest("mailto:name@example.com"));
```

`sendToURL` is also a function in the flash.net package

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

try

```
navigateToUrl(urlRequest, "_self");
```

from [API](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL())

Answer (score 1):

**2016 Update**

I know this is a **very** old question, however;

`navigateToURL(new URLRequest("mailto:name@domainname.com"), "_blank");`

Automatically opens a new email in Outlook without opening a new browser tab.

*Adobe Animate 2015.2*

Answer (score 0):

The mailprogram is opening because you gave a mail ID as URL.  I think your intention is sending mail when a user click on the link right?

And to open in same window use what CookieOfFortune is saying. In

```
navigateToUrl(urlRequest, "_self");
```

the second part, `_self`, is setting the target window as self. 
If you want to open in new window you have to use `navigateToUrl(urlRequest, "_blank");`

Answer (score 0):

We can use following code with `ExternalInterface` 
where 'url' is a `mailto:` URL. i.e.:

```
mailto:abc@example.com?subject=Hello&body=defg

//Mailto Links from Flash
ExternalInterface.call("function(link){var wEmail = window.open(link, '_blank'); setTimeout(function(){ wEmail.close();}, 70);}", url);
```